# Replace groups of text all together with gVim

Tags: regex, vim

Consider the following data:

```
Class   Gender  Condition   Tenis
A   Male    Fail Fail   33
A   Female  Fail NotFail    23
S  Male     Yellow     14
BC  Male    Happy Elephant  44
```

I have a comma separated value with unformatted tabulation (it varies among tabs and whitespaces).

In one specific column I have compound words which I would like to eliminate the space. In the above example, I would like to replace "Fail " with "Fail_" and "Happy" with "Happy_".

The result would be the following:

```
Class   Gender  Condition   Tenis
A   Male    Fail_Fail   33
A   Female  Fail_NotFail    23
S  Male     Yellow     14
BC  Male    Happy_Elephant  44
```

I already managed to do that in two steps:

```
:%s/Fail /Fail_/g
:%s/Happy /Happy_/g
```

**Question**: As I'm very new to gVim I am trying to implement these replacements all together, but I could not find how to do that*.

After this step, I will tabulate my data with the following:

```
:%s/\s\+/,/g
```

And get the final result:

```
Number,Gender,Condition,Tenis
A,Male,Fail_Fail,33
A,Female,Fail_NotFail,23
S,Male,Yellow,14
BC,Male,Happy_Elephant,44
```

<sub>On SO, I searched for `[vim] :%s two is:question` and some variations, but I could not find a related thread, so I guess I am lacking the correct terminology.</sub>

---

Edit: This is the actual data (with more than 1 million rows). The problem starts in the 12th column (e.g. "Fail Planting" should be "Fail_Planting").

```
SP1     51F001      3   1   1   2   3   2001    52  52  H   Normal          17,20000076 23,39999962 NULL    NULL
SP1     51F001      3   1   1   2   3   2001    53  53  F   Fail Planting   0   0   NULL    NULL
SP1     51F001      3   1   1   2   3   2001    54  54  N   Normal          13,89999962 0   NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Is it safe to assume the third word on the line will always require an underscore or is there any lines that would not fit this requirement?

Comment: Hmmm based on that data it looks like you do not always want to add an underscore (because the column contains single word values as well). That makes my macro answer no good =/

Comment: I think you're out of luck for doing it from the vim command line. Do you have access to a scripting language or a programming language (this wouldn't be too difficult in something like c#).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an expression on the right hand side of the substitution.

```
:%s/\(Fail\|Happy\) \|\s\+/\= submatch(0) =~# '^\s\+$' ? ',' : submatch(1).'_'/g
```

So this finds `Fail` or `Happy` or whitespace and then converts checks to see if the matched part is completely whitespace. It it is replace by a comma if it is not use the captured part and append an underscore. `submatch(0)` is the whole match and `submatch(1)` is the first capture group.

Take a look at `:h sub-replace-expression`. If you want to do something very complex define you can define a function.

---

Very magic version

```
:%s/\v(Fail|Happy) |\s+/\= submatch(0) =~# '^\v\s+$' ? ',' : submatch(1).'_'/g
```

Answer (score 6):

You have all the parts you just need to combine them together with `|`. Example:

```
:%s/\>\s\</_/g|%s/\s\+/,/g
```

I am using `\>` and `\<` to find words that only have one space between them so we can replace it with `_`.

For more help see:

```
:h /\>
:h :range
:h :bar
```

Comment: The big issue is you are overloading space as a both delimiter and a normal space inside a field. You maybe able to tweak your first substitution like so `:%s/\w\zs\s\ze\w/_/`. Note: this will probably end up being a trial and error process.

Comment: Now, I finally got your answer and the or operator (better late than never). I used `:%s/Fail /Fail_/g|%s/Happy /Happy_/g` and it worked. Thank you (+1).

Answer (score 5):

You could perhaps try a macro if there are certain conditions that are true (or write a vimscript, but my vimscript is very rusty). I will show a sample macro you could use:

- Go to first line in file after the headings
- press <kbd>q</kbd> to begin recording a macro
- press <kbd>t</kbd> to choose the register `t` for recording to (I use t for "temp")
- press <kbd>^</kbd> to move to the beginning of the line
- press <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> to move to the third word (move 2 words to the right)
- press <kbd>e</kbd> to move to the end of the word
- press <kbd>l</kbd> (letter l) to move right one character (to the space)
- press <kbd>r</kbd> to enter replace single character mode
- press <kbd>_</kbd> to enter an underscore
- press <kbd>j</kbd> to move down a line
- press <kbd>q</kbd> to stop recording the macro

Now that you have the macro stored in register `t` you can run the macro on every line in the file. If there are 100 lines in the file, you have already done 1 and there is a header, so you would type the following to run it on the remaining 98 lines:

- <kbd>9</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>

Comment: No problem. You can even store macros in your vimrc file if you have one that you use often. As for the triple compound words, a macro wouldn't work because it just repeats the same actions you recorded (which only handed a double compound word). Unless you can run a command on each line that could handle both situations (not sure if a macro records command line stuff too...something I should look into!).

Answer (score 2):

These two commands:

```
:%s/\(\a\) \(\a\)/\1_\2/g
:%s/\s\+/,/g
```

seem to work on your sample:

```
SP1,51F001,3,1,1,2,3,2001,52,52,H,Normal,17,20000076,23,39999962,NULL,NULL
SP1,51F001,3,1,1,2,3,2001,53,53,F,Fail_Planting,0,0,NULL,NULL
SP1,51F001,3,1,1,2,3,2001,54,54,N,Normal,13,89999962,0,NULL,NULL
```

but you have decimal numbers here with a comma as separator that will mess with the "comma-separated-ness" of your data. Changing those commas into periods beforehand might be a good idea:

```
:%s/,/./g

SP1,51F001,3,1,1,2,3,2001,52,52,H,Normal,17.20000076,23.39999962,NULL,NULL
SP1,51F001,3,1,1,2,3,2001,53,53,F,Fail_Planting,0,0,NULL,NULL
SP1,51F001,3,1,1,2,3,2001,54,54,N,Normal,13.89999962,0,NULL,NULL
```

Comment: `\(foo\)` is a capture group that you reuse in the replacement part with `\n`: `\1` for the first group, `\2` for the second… the regex is only meant for `letterspaceletter` and will probably need to be modified to accommodate all your requirements.